# How does my prof's logic work? Find four roots of $p(x)$.

Tags: roots, bisection

Below is the solution to a problem where you have to find four intervals of length $1/16$ that contain roots of $p(x)$.

Apparently,

> Since the cubic and quadratic terms have large negative coefficients, we suspect that the other two roots are close to x=1.

My problem with this is, if you make some roots within $0.0001$ "distance" of each other, there's no way on an exam you can use IVT and bisection method (the problem statement said we should use them) to find those two intervals of length $1/16$. Or even 0.1, it leaves you guessing all over the place.

Also, In Desmos I graphed the same function, but with even **more** negative coefficients for the cube and square and lo and behold, the roots were not around 1 anymore, unlike in the solution statement.

Is the solution's argument absurd, or am I missing something important? How would one solve this painlessly in a calculator-less, exam situation?

[image]

Comment: what is $p(x)$?

Comment: @gt6989b see the image. It's been there from the start.

Comment: i cannot see the image

Comment: $p'(1)\approx-600$ (unless my mental arithmetic failed me), so surely it makes sense to look for possible sign changes slightly above $1$, as the function is sharply decreasing at that point. The author thought about it slightly differently. Their way or my way, no big deal. Both motivated by the fact that for larger values of $x$ the quartic term will dominate, and its pointless to look there. The search for a point like $3/2$ might have easily come out empty. No guarantees here!

Answer (score 1):

For a quartic with positive fourth power term to have four roots it comes down from $(-\infty, +\infty)$ crosses the $x$ axis four times and heads off to $(+\infty,+\infty)$  With the tabluated values in hand, it looks like the fourth power term is already dominant by $-3$ and $+3$, so the roots need to be between those.  The sign changes locate two of them.  The fact that $f(1)$ is the smallest tabulated value gives a hint that the roots are nearby.  You are correct that if you make the second and third power terms more negative you can move the roots well away from $1$, but that is likely to depress $f(2)$ and make it closer to $0$ than $f(1)$.  I don't think the "large and negative" claim holds water, but the fact that $f(1)$ looks like a local minimum is more telling.

Answer (score 0):

$$225 x^4-210 x^3-812 x^2+706 x+315=0$$
$$(3 x-5) (3 x+1) (5 x-7) (5 x+9)=0$$

$$x_1=-\frac{9}{5},x=_2-\frac{1}{3},x_3=\frac{7}{5},x_4=\frac{5}{3}$$

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this misses the spirit of the question: yes, in this case you can get explicit solutions relatively easily; you could even get an algebra system to give you solutions even if you could not factor it completely. But the question is more along the lines of looking at the equation and guessing (although it should be an educated guess) what the solutions should more or less look like, with a minimum of calculation.